# SQL: CAST combined with window function causes syntax error

Tags: sql, mysql, casting, syntax-error, window-functions

I want to condense my database, which now contains a large number of values, to 1/12 of the original size by averaging twelve consecutive values.

To do this, I form the mean value using the types `TIMESTAMP` and `FLOAT(4,2)`. In order to average the `TIMESTAMP` properly, I first wanted to cast the `TIMESTAMP` into an `INT`, then calculate the average value with `AVG()` and finally cast the average value back into a `DATETIME`. During this operation, however, I get a syntax error that I cannot explain.

That is the respective query I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO condensed_12_current(time_mean, current_mean)
SELECT
  CAST(AVG(CAST(time as INTEGER)) AS DATETIME) OVER (
    ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS time_mean,
  AVG(current) OVER (
    ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS current_mean
FROM current
WHERE id % 12 = 0;
```

Caused Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEGER)) AS DATETIME) OVER (
    ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ' at line 3
```

I have tried many different versions of the CAST instruction, but none of them have produced the desired result. The only CAST statement that was syntactically correct was when I cast the AVG() value back to the original data type.

Table current has the following structure:
time as TIMESTAMP
current as FLOAT(4,2)
id as INT AUTO INCREMENT

Table condensed_12_current has the following structure:
time as TIMESTAMP
current as FLOAT(4,2)

MYSQL Ver 8.2.0 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell your database how to order the rows or it will process them in arbitrary order.  For example, to order rows by the `ID` column:

```
avg(current) over (
    order by id rows between 11 preceding and current row
    ) as current_mean
```

[Example at DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N27izmYe)

MySQL doesn't seem to support casting a `timestamp` to an `integer`.  You can use [`from_unixtime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)  and [`unix_timestamp()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) instead:

```
from_unixtime(avg(unix_timestamp(ts)) over
            (rows between 1 preceding and current row))
```

[Example at DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/byFdHJ7l)

Comment: I've added the "ORDER BY ID" and now i get an other error: #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '20220717113580.0000' for column 'time_mittelwert' at row 2

Answer (score 1):

`CAST()` is not a windowing operation, so we have an error looking at this expression:

```
CAST(AVG(CAST(time as INTEGER)) AS DATETIME) OVER (
    ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
```

Here, the `OVER` clause relative to the `CAST()` is not correct. That is, you must cast the *entire result of the window*. You need to take the average over a given window rather than a cast over the window:

```
CAST(   AVG(CAST(time as INTEGER)) OVER (
            ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        )  
    AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't seem to support casting timestamps to integer https://dbfiddle.uk/t4dIhFDe

Comment: AVG(CAST(time AS INTEGER)) already causes an error. Extending the parentheses around the window doesn't help either. @Andomar got to the point of it.

 "FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)) OVER (
    ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )) AS time_mean" solves the problem. Thanks guys!